# Angular: is it possible to bind value of attribute to other html attribute

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have two html elements and I want to bind the size of one to the size of another like:

```
<div id="elem1"> </div>

<div style="height:some binding expression to the height of elem1; 
     width:another binding expression to width of elem1"></div>
```

Is this even possible? The binding only needs to happen once.

Comment: Do they always need to be equal(page resize, ect) or simply on page load ?

Comment: @AndrewDonovan just on page load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **ng-style**  directive on the second element. You can set styling on the elements via object form, and is automatically updated when the value changes.

On page load, calculate the height of `elem1` and set it to a scope variable, lets say:

```
$scope.elemStyle = {
    height: calculated_elem1_height
}
```

Then your second element
`<div ng-style="elemStyle"></div>`

Every time you update the variable `$scope.elemStyle`, the DOM will be updated.

***EDIT***

`calculated_elem1_height` needs to be a string, Eg: "100px"

Answer (score 0):

$timeout will ensure the DOM is loaded

```js
var test = angular.module("myApp", []);
test.directive('equalTo', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function() {
      var e = angular.element(document.querySelector(attrs['element']))[0]
      element.css("width", e.offsetWidth + "px") 
      element.css("height", e.offsetHeight + "px")
    }, 0);
  };

});
```

```css
#elem1 {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
#elem2 {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="elem1"> </div>
  <div id="elem2" equal-to element="#elem1"></div>
</body>
```